# C# Console Problem

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, console, getter

Consider this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Game.Items
{
    class Item
    {
        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
        }

        private string description;
        public string Description
        {
            get { return this.description; }
        }

        public Item(string name, string description)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}
```

I then create a new object like this:

```
Item item1 = new Item("Item1", "Description...");
```

Now the problem, I cannot access properties of the object with the getter method, i.e. this doesn't work:

```
Console.WriteLine(item1.Name);
Console.WriteLine(item1.Description);
Console.ReadLine();
```

By "doesn't work" I mean when I click on "Start debugging", the console window appears but nothing is there, it's blank. However, this works fine:

```
Console.WriteLine(item1); // ToString()
Console.ReadLine();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Richard

Comment: If you haven't, try installing the 30 day free trial of Resharper - it will detect and offer to fix numerous things like namespace problems, protection problems and whatnot... as well as suggesting good naming conventions - good learning material.

Comment: When you say "this doesn't work", what exactly do you mean? Compiler error? Runtime error? Incorrect result? Crashing?

Comment: Is the newline printed or nothing at all? How about the `Console.ReadLine`? Does it work?

Comment: Please paste a complete program that demonstrates the problem, in other words, put everything in one file, remove everything that is unnecessary for demonstrating the problem, verify that you still have the problem, then paste it here.

Comment: Suggesting to close asn "no longer relevant" because he has an answer, that was specific to his complete problem (that he didn't post), and nobody with the same problem will stumble across this question. Besides, the subject line is bad. I may have to change my "top 10 worst subject lines" to a "top 20".

Comment: Agreed on the "close as no longer relevant".

Answer (score 3):

Works fine for me:

```
using System;

namespace Application
{
    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Item item1 = new Item("Item1", "Description...");
            Console.WriteLine(item1.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(item1.Description);
        }
    }
}
```

(With your class there as well.)

When you say "this doesn't work" what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: Well, when I click "Start debugging", the console window appears but it is blank. Nothing is there.

Thew two commands:

Console.WriteLine(item1.Name);
Console.WriteLine(item1.Description);

They do nothing.

Only this works (ToString()):

Console.WriteLine(item1);

Comment: Please add this information to your question (or someone with enough rep will sooner or later I guess ;  (also try including the actual code and class/file/namespace structure used)

Comment: Given that my short but complete program above works fine, it sounds like you're doing something strange - please post a short but complete program which shows this odd behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working your Main class in a project different than the Project where "Item" is contained? if so, then

- Reference the other project
- Mark your Item class as public

  ```
  public class Item {
      // your code
  }
  ```

Or you can try to access this way to see if the problem is related with namespaces

```
Console.WriteLine(Application.item1.Name);
Console.WriteLine(Application.item1.Description);
```

Also, put a pause after the execution, or else your console window will go without showing you anything

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

Check also the using clauses, according to last comment, you then have to use a using clause at the top of the file where you are trying to use the Item class

```
using Game;
```

Comment: About the only thing I could think of as well, declaring the class itself public if used outside of the project namespace...